# Low GPU usage on large model training with Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, gpu

I am training a rather large model (>2M parameters) with tensorflow, but as soon as I start training GPU activity drops to ~0 (2%, even less than baseline) and remains there. Attached is the nvtop graph during the process. I use `tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(gpu, True)` to limit the memory usage to what is needed, otherwise the nvtop graph shows 100% memory usage, and GPU activity still remains at 2%.

Tensorflow definitely sees my GPU (it definitelly does something with it based on nvtop display) and I use tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy.

I use
`Tensorflow = 2.6.2 (same result with 2.7)`
`cuda = 11.2`
`cudnn = 8.1`
GPU: RTX 4080, driver 525..89.02
Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
`batch size = 32`
`.buffer(500)`
[nvtop GPU usage at start of training](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UqP2p.png)

I tried varying batch size, model size etc... but nothing works. I tried running some small benchmarking models for tensorflow (e.g. [this one](https://github.com/DevloperHS/Analytics-Vidhya-Projects/blob/main/GPU%20And%20CPU%20Performance%20Test/GPU%20%26%20CPU%20BENCHMARK%20ONLY.ipynb)) and I got decent result with some ~50% GPU usage.

As I suspected that the CPU might be lagging behind in loading training files, I tried `.prefetch(tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)` on my dataset, even with custom values of prefetch, nothing changed.

I tried using tensorflow 2.11 on a GTX 3070, that did not work either.

Comment: This just means you are not compute bound, and you did not mention the actual model or dataset.

Comment: Good point, my dataset consists of cubes of images (64*64*30) and the model is a convolutional NN in a bunch of residual blocks. 
Yes, I realised now that the CPU is my issue here. I now use `.prefetch(100)` on my dataset which is helping for the first few iterations of each epoch past the first one, but I wonder if there are other tricks to know to make my pipeline more efficient.

Comment: According to my system monitor though I hardly ever saturate my CPUs. Only when prefetching do I see 1 (out of 16) of my CPUs work at a 100%. That's when I get a few iterations at full speed. The rest of the time my CPUs run under 20% of their capacities. It seems like I'm underutilizing my harder by far.